# Execute JavaScript on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I have a form displayed on a layer (I'm using ChicoUI as UI Framework), everything is managed through Google Apps Script. Everything went fine (The submit sends data to a google spreadsheet), but I need the following: When the submit button is pressed I need to change the layer content through a simple js line. to display the classic "Thank you message" with a close button.

As far as I saw, everything leads to return something in the gs script, for instance in the doGet() method.

It´s posible to execute a framework method instead of returning something? Remember that I have no issues with JS, but with Google Apps Script.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you explain "executing framework method instead of returning something" by posting code snippet?

Comment: Code snippet is a must here, it looks like all you want is to execute a `function` when the script in google server is done, wich is exactly what `withSuccessHandler` does, and is the only way to communicate back.

Comment: @user1989 I mean that when I submit the form, I must be able to execute something like $('modal').content("Thank you!").

Comment: Thanks @Kriggs! Will try your solution. The other thing is, I don´t want to be redirected to any other page. I need to stay on that page. (In order to avoid losing the modal and the page from where I'triggered the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I have done with jQuery. I think it might help to understand what you want to achieve.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(e){
           alert("Thank you"); // Here you can write thank you message.
        }).myFunction(this);  // passing forms data to apps script.
      });
    });
</script>

<form id="myform">                   
  <input name="user1" id="user" type="text" value="">
  <input name="user2" id="user" type="text" value="">
  <input name="user3" id="user" type="text" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"> 
</form>
```